# Normalize positive distributed time series data without window parameters

Tags: data, factor-models, normalization

I have a piece of daily volume and a piece of daily trades data, now I divide them and I get volume/trades as a factor. This factor has positive value and I want it to be normalized to predict the next-day return by its sign. My solution is to revise the factor as
 `factor = factor - factor.rolling.mean(window)`. In this way the factor indeed contains both negative and positive value. However, it uses `window` as an extra parameter. The problem is: Is there any normalization method without using an extra parameter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about standard way: (factor(t)-mean)/stdDev ?

Comment: That is known as *standardization*, while the OP is asking about *normalization* (but they use the term incorrectly, so perhaps your solution is fine for them).

Comment: Actually I only need the sign of the factor, so this standard method is equivalent to factor minus mean. Yet the mean needs a window.

Comment: @RichardHardy Here I didn't distinguish standardization and normalization. What I request is transforming the original data into a piece of data distributed equally into negative side and positive side.

Comment: @atlantic0cean, OK, so what you want is neither std. nor norm. but rather some other transformation (perhaps mean-centering or median-centering). It is usually helpful to stick to established terminology, so it could make sense to edit the post accordingly.